# How to execute unbalanced dataset in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing, read.csv

I have following dataset. I want to do a load test in JMeter with this csv file. But I cannot read the file because all the columns are not filled with data. How do I write the code for that in JMeter?

Dataset:
[image]

[image]

Comment: what your "code" is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Run all these rows one by one. So I can get the performance details of this load. The thing is if all these columns are filled I can easily run this dataset without any code. But in some rows, as u can see we don't have data. And it is the real scenario. So I want to read these data through this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `test.csv` file like this:

```
A,B,C
A1,B1,C1,
A2,,C2
,B3,C3
```

Or if you prefer screenshots from Excel:

[image]

If you setup[CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) like this:

[image]

It will normally read the data, when there is nothing in the "cell" the relevant [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) will just be empty. You can observer JMeter Variables (and properties) with their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)

[image]

Comment: I figured it out. Put all those SCNo into one column like this "53424,54799" and set excel column as "text". It automatically numbers. Then we can run it without any JSSR code and it doesn't matter if there's unbalance number of data in each row.